# System.InvalidOperationException: Internal Connection Fatal Error. when opening sql connection

Tags: c#, sql, fatal-error

I've just started playing around with SQL on C#, and I'm trying to connect to a remote SQL server. I've added my IP to the list of hosts that have remote access permission.

My code keeps producing this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Internal Connection Fatal Error.
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPocessHeader<>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer<>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByteArray<.Byte[] buff, Int32  offset, Int32 len, Int32& totalRead>

The trace is actually longer than that, but those are the first few lines.

This is the code that's causing the error (My actual connection string has the correct username, password, and database name):

```
connectionString = "Data Source=173.254.28.27,3306;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=myDatabase;User Id=myUserName;Password=myPassword;";
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    try { myConnection.Open(); }
    catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.ToString()); }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED**

If you are using `MySQL Server` then your connection string is wrong!

try this connectionString :

```
_connectionStr = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                Server = "173.254.28.27",
                Database = myDatabase,
                UserID = myUserName,
                Password = myPassword,
                ConnectionTimeout=60,
                Port = 3306,
                AllowZeroDateTime = true
            };
            _con = new MySqlConnection(_connectionStr.ConnectionString);

            try
            {
                _con.Open();
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error, help i can't get connected!");
            }
```

If you are using `SQLServer` try disabling Connection Pool through connection string!

by adding :

> `Pooling=false`

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did, and got an error that says **System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'pool'.**

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the System.ArgumentException, but I'm still getting the initial error. :(

Comment: What is your configuration? and DBMSSOCN is the default value of Network Library. So if you do not use it on your connection string, then it will use the default value which is "DBMSSOCN"

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Do you mean the server configuration?

Comment: .Net is version 4. The database is on a shared hosting server and they use MySQL v5.5.30

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't recognize the type MySqlConnectionStringBuilder. Do you happen to know the namespace that I need to use? Or do I have to download the class somewhere?

Comment: 1- you have to download and install .Net MySQL Connector then import MySQL.Data in your project references then add using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

Comment: Hi Obama, I tried with above  code. But it thrown error "At line:15 char:27
+                 _con.Open();
+                           ~
An expression was expected after '('.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedExpression".

Comment: Can you please correct me?

Answer (score 0):

Create a udl file, if it connects then the problem is the code / application, if it does not connect, then it's your firewall, connections string, dll library etc. Well the important thing here is probably the connection string. Do the following: create an empty text file and rename it "myconnection.udl". Now double click on the file and it will launch an applet. You can configuer the connection to your database and test it. (it will pick up registered connection libraries etc). If it give OK, then open the udl file in notepad, you will see the correct connection string. Paste to your app connection settings. UDL files are generally misunderstood. They are simply a text file that holds the connection settings. They then call the connection dll. If the udl file works then you have a correct connection string 100%